# Google Maps Engine Image Layer Events

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-maps-engine

I'm am trying to use a maps engine layer in google maps api v3 and am running into issues with events and [opacity](https://code.google.com/p/maps-engine/issues/detail?id=30&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Summary%20Internal) (accepted enhancement) for raster layers.

The issue is that **raster** type data does not allow any events as far as I can tell.

```
var layer2 = new google.maps.visualization.MapsEngineLayer({
    layerId: '15658084116283052074-13711557424617485464',
    map: map,
    clickable: true,
    suppressInfoWindows: false
});

google.maps.event.addListener(layer2, 'click', function (event) {
    alert('click');
});
```

[Demo (jsbin)](http://jsbin.com/noner/1/edit?html,output) with vector maps engine layer and raster layer here. Is there something I'm missing or is it simply not implemented?

Documentation:[Maps Engine Layers](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/mapsenginelayers)

Edit: I would like to get the **pixel value** of the raster.

Comment: Never used that, but the doc says *click is fired when a feature in the layer is clicked*. As I understand it, it's not when the layer itself is clicked (?).

Comment: what is the 'feature' in a raster or image layer? the tile, pixel?

Answer (score 0):

The click event in a DMEL is fired when a *feature* is clicked.  In Maps Engine, a feature is the same as defined in GeoJSON.  That is: a single geometry, or table row in your data set.

As raster layers are not attached to a tabular data source, they don't contain individual features like points and shapes.

Raster layers are much like the base layer in the map however, so you can grab a click event at the map level.  e.g.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function (event) {
  alert(event.latLng);
});
```

I'm not sure what your intention is beyond just a lat/lng pair though.  If you wish to interrogate pixel data you may be better off putting the raw data into a table.